# EC2 via autoscaling, how long until tags propagate?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-cloudformation, cloud-init

I'm trying to use `userdata` to run some code on autoscaled EC2 instances. It's important that the instance tags ("name", etc) are already set. I know that doesn't happen immediately on creation.

As a start, I'm adding `sleep 20` in my userdata script. Obviously that's a code smell.

So, **how long does it take tags to propagate**? How can I detect it- can I use instance metadata (`http://169.254.169.254/latest/`) to detect that the machine is healthy?

If not, I know I could determine my instance ID and then query the API (perhaps with boto) and wait for tags. There are several yaks necessary to do this- for instance, I must ensure dependencies are installed and that I have IAM Role rights. So I'd prefer not to go that route.

Comment: @hellov Linux- modern Ubuntu. I can watch tag assignment in the console, certainly it doesn't happen at "zero seconds". I just can't figure out how to work with that.